# Best Practice for Storing Cognito Identity Pool Ids

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When working with Cognito Identity Pools (federated identities), what's the best practice for storing the unique ids of the pools that my users will need to have access to?  I'm thinking about them as secrets, as they're required for use with the API actions needed to get credentials for working with secure resources (e.g. GetId, GetCredentialsForIdentity), which are public APIs.

Comment: `IdentityPoolIds` are done to be used in the client, it is just a pointer to the service not a decryption key or secret.
The security of an identityPoll stands on the role and policies you have attached to it.

Comment: Read this https://hackernoon.com/authentication-with-aws-cognito-bc8d1484600b. Although I do not understand why Postgres is chosen over DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

What [Madeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8868419/madeo) has stated in the comments is the right concept. The Identity ID/Identity Pool ID itself is not a sensitive piece of information. Identity ID is defined as a unique identifier for the Identity Pool, and it can be operated on in the client-side of your application.

For security, you would need to make sure the JWT token from the User Pool is passed to the Identity Pool API call in a secure fashion (or wherever you are getting the token from, be it Facebook/Twitter/etc).

Comment: This sort of makes sense, but here's my confusion.  Let's say I have two users, we'll call them 'abc' and 'xyz'.  User 'abc' is a general user, no special privileges.  User 'xyz' is an admin user, they have some additional privileges to do certain things that general users cannot, say for example make calls to a specific API endpoint.  If user 'abc' somehow discovers the Cognito identity pool id used by admin users such as 'xyz', they could theoretically elevate their own privileges by crafting the right API calls to Cognito to get temporary creds. Or am I thinking about that wrong?

Comment: You are indeed correct. For the same reason, you would need to secure such privileges(admin/confidential information) behind a 'logins' map. The logins map ensures only authenticated users can leverage authorization sanctions. Kindly refer to this API documentation to know more about the [logins map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html). Feel free to ask if you have any more questions about the same. 

In my answer, when I talked about the JWT token passed to the Identity Pool, I basically referred to the Logins Map.